# Implementing Multiple SQLite ORM Libraries In a Single Android Project

Tags: android-asynctask, android-sqlite, android-room, greendao, activeandroid

Currently, we are using  **ActiveAndroid** ORM in our project. We have thousands of records in a single SQLite Table. When we run multiple queries (with conditions) and shows results on the views. Our app hangs, skip android windows frames, the android screen turns black and app does not respond. Following warning are shows

`CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 696 bytes, free space 346 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes`

We want to run an Asynchronous query in the background and shows the results on the UI Thread.

Is ActiveAndroid provide Asynchronous query, if not can we use parallel ORM like  **Room/GreenDAO/etc.** with  **ActiveAndroid** library Or any other library to run query asynchronously?

Comment: You may try JDXA ORM for Android. JDXA supports asynchronous queries and can work with an existing database schema. Disclaimer: I am the architect of JDXA ORM.

Comment: Try to find solution in these questions https://stackoverflow.com/q/34325327/1429387 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/44872233/1429387 (not using ORM).